# Dynamically add Server 2008 NLB Nodes

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, nlb

I have a small NLB cluster for Terminal Servers. One of the things we're looking at doing for this particular project (this is for a college class) is dynamically creating Terminal Servers.

What we've done is create policies for a certain OU, that sets the proper TS Farm properties and installs the Terminal Server role and NLB feature. Now what we'd like to do is create a script to be run on our Domain Controller to add hosts to the preexisting NLB cluster. On our Server 2008 R2 Domain Controller, I was thinking of running the following PowerShell script I've kind of hacked together.

Any thoughts on if this will work? Is there any way I can trigger this script to run on the DC once all the scripts to install roles are done on the various Terminal Servers?

Thanks very much in advance!!

```
Import-Module NetworkLoadBalancingClusters

$TermServs = @()
$Interface = "Local Area Connection"

$ou = [ADSI]"LDAP://OU=Term Servs,DC=example,DC=com"
foreach ($child in $ou.psbase.Children)
{
  if ($child.ObjectCategory -like '*computer*') {$TermServs += $child.Name}
}

foreach ($TS in $TermServs)
{
  Get-NlbCluster 172.16.0.254 | Add-NlbClusterNode -NewNodeName $TS -NewNodeInterface $Interface
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you running on the TS servers?  Are you adding these TS servers at any kind of regular interval?  If you are, then the script you want to run on the DC could be scheduled to run every X minutes/Y hours.  I don't have an environment to test this.